# Geometry following a curved object

Tags: bezier-curves, shrinkwrap

I was looking for a way to snap one object ( wooden plank ) in a rounded surface ( sphere ).
actually i'm using a shrinkwrap modifier but the result is not what i want..

[image]

I would like that the wooden plank follow the curve of the sphere like the brick follow the curved surface in this picture.

[image: https://imgur.com/qtS2cv0]

I hope I explained myself.

Comment: Could you please embed the screenshots directly in your post? Use the `Edit` button then the Image icon. Thx

Comment: Already tried, the image link tell me that the image is not supported, even if i insert the url that i shared with you

Answer (score 1):

1. create a 2D `lattice` and match it with your tile
2. use the `Lattice modifier` on the tile and assign the create lattice
3. parent the tile to the lattice
4. add the `Shrink wrap` modifier to the lattice
5. Enable `Snap to Face` on your target object
6. move the lattice on the target object.

Play around with shrinkwrap offset, lattice resolution and subdiv modifiers to tune it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Shrinkwrap modifier will need the wood to have plenty of edges to make the turn first of all BUT it will flatten the wood. So, make first only a 2d plane to Shrinkwrap that is the size of the wood's X and Y but not depth.

Shrinkwrap (perhaps by projection, not "nearest surface point" as is in the blurry image). Position. Duplicate. Apply the modifier.

Now you can Extrude the 2D pieces into the 3D planks you envision.